# Error utilizando Estructuras unidades en C como Pila

Tags: c, punteros

Estoy tratando de implementar estructuras en C de forma anidada para utilizarla como si fuera una Pila, estoy teniendo problemas, Estoy tratando de implementar solucion al siguiente enunciado y el error que me arroja.

[image: Enunciado]

Mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 10
int contador = 0;
 //Estructura Cantante
struct Cantante {
 int top;
 unsigned capacity;
 char nombre[ARRSIZE];
 int edad;
 int numDiscos;
 char titulo[30];
 int numCanciones;
};

struct Stack{   
int top;
unsigned capacity;  
struct Cantante* elemento[ARRSIZE]; 
};
typedef struct Stack st;    


//Inicializar Pila
struct Stack* inicializarPila(unsigned capacity)
{ 
  struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
  stack->capacity = capacity;
  stack->top = -1;
  return stack;
}

//Compruebo si esta vacia
int vacia(st *s){
 if (s->top == -1)
  return 1;
  else
  return 0;
}

//Compruebo si esta llena
int llena(st *s){
 if (s->top == ARRSIZE - 1)
 return 1;
else
return 0;
}

//Agregar elemento a la pila
void push(st *s, st x){
 if (llena(s)) {
 printf("Pila llena");
}  else {
   s->top++;
   s->elemento[s->top] = x;
}
contador++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{}
```

El error que obtengo al construir es:

Artistas.c:64:27: error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct Cantante *' from type 'st' {aka 'struct Stack'}

Que corresponde a la linea de:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo es que una pila no se rellena con otras pilas, sino con elementos.

Tu tienes una estructura *pila* que es capaz de almacenar objetos de tipo `Cantante*`:

```
struct Stack{  // <<--- Estructura pila 
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;  
    struct Cantante* elemento[ARRSIZE];
    //     ~~~~~~~~~  <<--- Elementos de tipo Cantante*
};
```

Así pues, la función `push` debería recibir un puntero de tipo `Cantante`, ya que lo que pretendes aquí es añadir un elemento a la pila:

```
void push(st *s, Cantante* x){
```